# Create a utf8 file in linux in c programing

Tags: c, linux, file, utf-8

I have to create a utf8 file (say utf8_test.txt)  in linux (Ubuntu), in c.
I tried fopen(), but it create hte file depending on the Locale - as the locale was en_IN, it created in Ascii I guess.

Is there any interface or function by which I can specify the format of the file to open or I need to add some byte in the beginning of the file, so that the OS understands that it is a UTF8 file?

Please give your valuable inputs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

GLib contains routines for working with UTF-8 text, and libiconv can be used to convert between various charsets, including UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

*fopen* can be used to write a binary stream of data.  Your locale is not relevant.

You should check whether you are actually sending a UTF-8 byte stream to the file.  You can do this by running a hex-editor on the file, e.g. *xxd*, and seeing if a UTF-8 sequence appears in the file.

If you do not have UTF-8 bytes in the file then the byte stream you are sending to the file is incorrect.

If you do have UTF-8 bytes in the file then your issue is just one of display.